# efficient way of counting pixels in a contour

Tags: opencv

Given a contour, what is the efficient way of counting the pixels that belong inside the contour?

I tried using **opencv** function
    cv::pointPolygonTest()

but the function is highly inefficient and takes a lot of time for bigger contours.
Please advice

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have extracted the contours with the `findContours()` function.

Then, you can use the `contourArea()` directly.

```
cout << Contour area is << contourArea(contours[k]) ;
```

Comment: hi @vasile  i am using `cv::findcontours()` to extract contours. However i also need the `xy-coordinates` of all the pixels lying inside the contour and store it as a `std::vector` to be used later. that is why i use `cv::pointPolygonTest()` . Could you suggest a better way?

Comment: hmm, you can try to make a mask out of the contour (something like a fillPoly()) to a blank image. So you will have an image with ones where pixels are inside contour, and zeros outsize.

Comment: From documentation of contourArea in OpenCV, "The function computes a contour area. Similarly to moments() , the area is computed using the Green formula. Thus, the returned area and the number of non-zero pixels, if you draw the contour using drawContours() or fillPoly() , can be different. Also, the function will most certainly give a wrong results for contours with self-intersections."

Answer (score 1):

If `contourArea` doesn't give you expected result, you can follow this approach:

1. Copy the contour in a new empty Mat
2. Apply `countNonZero` on the new submatrix and you will get the number of non-black pixel

   ```
       //1. Copy the contour in a new empty Mat
       Rect cRect = boundingRect(*it); //it is an iterator for your contours vector
       Mat subImg = dilatedImg(cRect);
       double cArea = countNonZero(subImg);
   ```

Note: if you doesn't have a binary image, you may need to threshold it before to count only the right pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have a simple recursive traversal that fills the area started from a single contour point. It will be efficient if it goes col-first I think so you can use the row iterator.

If you care about efficiency the most, you can perhaps unroll the recursion into loops and do for-unlooping.